# How to make the parent steps red in the Allure report when using logging.error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, allure

The report has nested steps, the test collects errors to output them at the end, when an error occurs, logging.error is used to display the error in the report, the logging.error step itself is red, but the parent steps in which logging.error is located are not red, how to make the parent steps turn red too

Project:

```py
import allure
import logging


class E:
    def __init__(self):
        self.errors = True

    def add(self, result):
        if not result:
            logging.error("error")
            self.errors = False


def test_1(driver):
    e = E()
    with allure.step("open page"):
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
    with allure.step("checks"):
        with allure.step("check 1"):
            e.add("youtube" not in driver.current_url)
        with allure.step("checks 2"):
            e.add("youtube" in driver.current_url)

    assert e.errors
```

allure report:
[image: report]

Is it possible to make the parent steps (“checks” and “check 2”) red?
Maybe there are other ways to do a soft check?

I found an implementation in Java, maybe there is something similar in Python:

```java
Allure.LIFECYCLE.fire((StepEvent) context -> context.setStatus(Status.FAILED));
```

Comment: @Guilherme Machado no :(